# Cleaning/scrubbing asbestos from the air and heating ducts?

Tags: asbestos, air-quality

I'm concerned that there may be airborne asbestos fibers. 
We just discovered that there is an asbestos flue pipe that was compromised in the attic when the previous owner of the house converted to forced air heating.

There's new ducting that runs to each room of the house. I'm concerned that during the conversion asbestos was released into the attic while they were running the flexible ducts.

I'm concerned that there is asbestos in the air in the attic. I'm also concerned that there is asbestos in the forced air ducts (they got in there bc asbestos was in the air when they were running the ducts to each room)

We have not moved into the house yet.

What can we do to scrub the air and the forced air system?

Can I rent air scrubbers and run them while I run the forced air system?

Answer (score 5):

Asbestos removal is very much the job for experts. If there is a chance that it has become airborne, you really need to call in a licensed professional to evaluate and, if necessary, remediate.

**This is not a do-it-yourself project.**

Comment: For something this obvious you can use a DIY testing kit.

Comment: A DIY kit for getting an air sample? or dust sample? or...?